# What does げ mean as a suffix?

Tags: words, morphology

I found this sentence

> 部長は満足げに顎を引く

How the suffix げ affects the word 満足?

Answer (score 0):

In Kanji, it is 満足気.
This 気 means "look like" or "seem like." Probably, words like air, appearance or atmosphere would explain well.

So, you can say "彼は満足気だ。" but not "私は満足気だ。" because you can be sure that you are satisfied.